# Which programming language use to develop this server side script - rpg combat system game

Tags: php, multiplayer

I want to explain what I need to do and with what language i can write down the code:

I'm developing an rpg online and I'm facing the combat system. What i have is this ->

0# players press a button who put them in the tabase, so they are listening for a battle.

1# What I want now is that the server script who is running in background check in the database all the players who are listening and waiting for a battle.

2# Then the script have to take two players each and put them in another table called "battle".

Now something I don't know how to manage:
3 a# Players, from the the moment they press the button, they check on the DB "battle" if they have an opponent. If they find a rival then they pass to the the battle screen.

3 b# the server itself switch the screen to the couples of players who are in the battle field on the db to the battle one.

Now the battle can start.

Another thing I want to understand is this one: How can I make the sincronism between the two players? I want to implement a countdown for each turn of one minute.

The programmin languages that I know are the follow: Html, Css, Php, MySql, Javascript, Ajax, Jquery.

I don't know which language use for the server management.. ( is it possible to have a server -> client push notification, instead of the classic client -> server -> client ? )

Thanks for the help.

Comment: node.js and websockets for your server connect.

Comment: This probably belongs on http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/  Unfortunately, the post flag dialog has no option for recommending that the question be moved to gamedev.

Answer (score 4):

The programming language is just a tool. You can develop this in PHP, Python, Ruby, .NET and probably many others. The choice of language should be so the language is confortable to you and the task you want to achieve and does not restrict you.

HTML and CSS are not programming languages. AJAX is not language as well. jQuery is JavaScript framework/library and not stand-alone language. MySQL is database server (although you have to use the SQL language).

Since you already know PHP, start with PHP. Either you will expand your knowledge of PHP, or you'll find what aspects of the language limit your creativity in the solving of the problem, and you'll know what to search for in the next language.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use either ASP.NET with lots of AJAX/jQuery, PHP with lots of AJAX/jQuery or just Flash with ActionScript.

My recommendation is to use PHP + AJAX + jQuery. If you're really experienced in Flash, then you can use that, but it needs some epic knowledge of Flash to do a RPG.